# How do I build multiple CodeIgniter image galleries that have the same setup and different content?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, MVC, and OOP. I'm trying to make two image galleries that rely on different content, but are the same setup and functionality. What's the best way to set this up? Should I create a library containing all the functionality and call it in my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC, you want to make sure your data gathering (model), logic (controller), and display (view) are logically separated. In order to do this, you'll need to have some common method of putting together your image gallery data that you create in your model and pass to your view through your controller. So let's consider a hyper-simplistic model function like this:

```
function getImages($param)
{
    if ($param)
    {
        return array(
                array('id'=>1, 'caption'=>'Image 1', 'url'=>'/images/image1.jpg'),
                array('id'=>2, 'caption'=>'Image 2', 'url'=>'/images/image2.jpg')
        )
    }
    else
    {
        return array(
                array('id'=>3, 'caption'=>'Image 3', 'url'=>'/images/image3.jpg'),
                array('id'=>4, 'caption'=>'Image 4', 'url'=>'/images/image4.jpg')
        )
    }
}
```

I'm just using `$param` here to be either true or false to fulfill your requirement for "different content" formatted in the same way. So now that you have this function in your **Images** model, you can call it from your controller like this:

```
$images = $this->Images->getImages($param);
```

Now that you have the data in a consistent format, you know that you can always pass this array of images to an images view that always expects a certain format (in this case, an array or arrays that have basic image data in them).

Now you'll want to create an image_gallery view that basically looks like this:

```
<div id="image_gallery">
    <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" />
        <div class="image_caption"><?php echo $image['caption'] ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Of course your actual gallery is probably going to look much different, but the idea here is that, if your image information is consistent, you shouldn't have any troubles creating your image gallery. The last piece of the puzzle is sending the images data into the view, and that is done like this from your controller:

```
$data = array();
$data['images'] = $images; //this is the var from above when we called $this->Images->getImages($param)

$this->load->view('image_gallery', $data);
```

Now that we have that slot in the `$data` array called "images", we will be able to access `$images` in our image_gallery view.

Of course, you don't always need to call views from your controllers. Indeed, it often makes sense to call views from inside views, but this depends entirely on your requirements. Sometimes it even makes sense to call views and return them as strings from a library, but just a fair warning: doing this can lead you easily away from the simplicity of the MVC approach.

Comment: So, if I was looking to do multiple galleries then I would just have separate methods in my controller that call to my model then send that info to my view?

Comment: @evilrobotz I'm not sure exactly what your setup is, but imagine you have a page that has 2 image galleries on it, each with different content. You could get the data like this: `$data['images'] = $this->Images->getImages(true); $gallery1 = $this->load->view('image_gallery', $data, TRUE); $data['images'] = $this->Images->getImages(false); $gallery2 = $this->load->view('image_gallery', $data, TRUE);`. The third parameter in the view loader returns the view as a string. You can then insert those strings into any view you like or you can make those calls directly from one of your views.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear with my question. I managed to figure it out not long after I asked. Thank you for your detailed answers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, creating a library and accepting initialization parameters (primarily name of the current gallery to be displayed or modified) is the way you will want to go.